# Last insert id value store to same table another specific column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i had following table and columns

```
Table Name = users
column = user_id, name, email, password, status, identity
```

i'm using following query for insert data to table `users`

```
$name             =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email           =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$password        =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtPassword']);
$password        =    md5($password);  //===Encrypt Password

if(isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) //===When I will Set the Button to 1 or Press Button to register

{
$query    =    "insert into users(name,email,pasword,status,identity)values('$name','$email','$password','1','0')";

$res    =    mysql_query($query);
header('location:success_register.php');//Redirect To Success Page
}
```

what i am asking is, i want store last id to column `identity` also

for example: if last `user_id= 10`, `identity` also will be = `10`. i mean get last id then store that id to `identity` column

**Result will be look like this**

```
user_id     name        email          password    status    identity
5           aa          aaa@ab.com     ****        1         5
6           bbb         bbb@ac.com     ****        1         6
```

how to do it,?

Comment: PHP has a function for accessing this information.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` and switch to `PDO` and you won't have these kind of problems.

Comment: You could use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that fills in `identity` with `new.user_id`.

Comment: Why do you need two columns with the same value?

Comment: Explain the need of such table structure please?

Comment: @nextgtech in my application there is different types users, this is a school/educational based projects, not only one admin here, many admins, teachers, students, etc... some times we can't use user_id for get user data to other admin account... if use user_id it complicated for me, may be other developers can do it easily, but for me not sure.

Comment: If you want to use that `identity` only for reference, you can use a `VIEW` over adding a column to the table. View won't add bytes to your table.

Comment: `create view users_data as select *, userid as identity from users`

Comment: And learn about prepared Statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MYSQL`, you have alternative possibility to find it, when you think `last_insert_id()` is not working. You may require to have `SELECT` privilege on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and its tables.

If you have that privileges, try the following query.

```
$query = "insert into users( name, email, pasword, status, identity )"
         . " values( '$name', '$email', '$password', '1',"
         . " ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"
         . "   WHERE TABLE_NAME='users' and TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() )"
         . " )";
```

---

And, lastly, suggesting to stop using deprecated API.

Answer (score 1):

**You are looking for:**

> [mysql_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

```
mysqli_insert_id(mysqli $link)//for mysqli
PDO::lastInsertId()//for PDO
```

**Other Approach:**
if your id column is auto increment and not random then you can select the max id(everytime just after your insert query) from the users table and insert it into whatever column you want.

```
$id=mysql_result(mysql_query(select max(user_id)
from users),0);
```

***Dont use mysql_* as they are depracated.***

Comment: for mysqli, connection parameter has to be passed ... **mysqli_insert_id($link)**

Comment: @user1844933 yeah correct,thats why i have given the link for OP to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Save last insert id like this:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

and use it in next insert

Answer (score 0):

here is what you are looking for. `Select max(user_id)+1` and store it in a variable.
Now you need to pass this variable in user_id and identity parameter.

Note that even though user_id is auto increment, it will allow you to insert the new row with specified user_id

Comment: This will be wrong if another client has inserted a row right after this client.

Comment: Then the only way is to fire an update query after inserting the row in the table. Why you want to do this @mans ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can also put it like this

```
$lastID = MySQLI_insert_id($DBcon); //where Dbcon is your connection to your database
```

and then

```
$query    =  "insert into users(name,email,pasword,status,identity)values('$name','$email','$password','1','$lastID')";

$res    =  mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to insert number of rows in the table after the insert:
It may useful to you

```
$query    =    "insert into users(name,email,pasword,status,identity)values('$name','$email','$password','1','0',(select COUNT(*)+1 FROM users))";
```

Comment: The number of rows is not the same as the auto-increment ID, if there have ever been deletions.

Comment: So you may replace the select query with 
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME =  'users'

Comment: What if another client has inserted another row at the same time? Why are you going to such great lengths to avoid using `mysql_insert_id()` or `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

Comment: @Barmar: AFAIK, it should not affect it as it should return based on current connection session.

Comment: The Query must be complete execution, at that time whatever the auto-increment value it is allotted to user_id and identity

Comment: If you don't want risk try another query with the update.
mysql_insert_id() returns output after the query execution.